# VueJS app not loading js files in kubernetes

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, kubernetes

I have a VueJS app running out of a Docker image in kubernetes. As soon as there is more than one replica / pod the client cannot load the app - many, but not all, calls to load files return a 404.

I assume that is because they are sent to a different pod than the one originally servicing the request.

How can this be fixed?

This is my setup:

- VueJS app (node.js-Server) running from a Docker image in kubernetes.
- Service and endpoint in kubernetes above that.
- nginx ingress in kubernetes as the next outward layer (see below).
- haproxy firewall such that myapp.mydomain.com/ gets routed to the ingress on k8s.

This is an example call which gets a 404 returned:
GET https://myapp.mydomain.com/js/chunk-d18c0136.7a3f0664.js

This is my service spec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG_SHORT}
  labels:
    app: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG}
  selector:
    app: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}
```

This is my nginx ingress spec:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG_SHORT}
  labels:
    app: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "30"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG_SHORT}
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - host: ${CI_APPLICATION_HOST}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG_SHORT}
                port:
                  number: 80
```

As a workaround we've configured the firewall to speak directly with only one pod, or running only one replica.

Setting session-stickyness "cookie" on the nginx ingress doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this was a complete red herring.

In the end, the problem was a typo in the external proxy routing - only two of six nodes were correctly configured and reachable. That's why "most" requests returned a 404 - the node couldn't be found.